# What's the difference between "no-CORS-safelisted request-header" and "CORS-safelisted request-header"?

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch

I read the specification and there seems to be no difference between them. Why is "no" added before it?

> A no-CORS-safelisted request-header name is a header name that is a byte-case-insensitive match for one of
> `Accept`
> `Accept-Language`
> `Content-Language`
> `Content-Type`
> To determine whether a header header is a no-CORS-safelisted request-header, run these steps:
> 1.If header’s name is not a no-CORS-safelisted request-header name, then return false.
> 2.Return whether header is a CORS-safelisted request-header.

source:
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#no-cors-safelisted-request-header
https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-request-header

Comment: What is the relationship between step 1 and step 2?

Comment: It looks like first "no-CORS-safelisted" and then "CORS-safelisted."